# Keras - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_index' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have created my deep neural network model based on `LSTM` using `Keras` on `Tensorflow` backend. When I call the`fit` function of my model, getting the `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_index' referenced before assignment`. **I have tried the answers provided to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935988/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-batch-index-referenced-before-assignment), but they did not work for me.** Some others recommended to downgrade `Python`'s version to `3.6`, but this did not fix the issue as well. The error stacktrace points exactly [this line of the code of Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L205).

p.s. I am using the latest stable versions of `keras` and `tensorflow` which are `2.3.1`, and `2.0.0`, respectively. And my `Python`'s version is `3.7`.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, GlobalMaxPooling1D, SpatialDropout1D

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'


def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', header=1)

    split_frac = 0.8  # 80% train, 20% test
    split_id = int(split_frac * len(df))

    X_train, y_train = df.iloc[:split_id, :-1].values, df.iloc[:split_id, -1].values
    X_test, y_test = df.iloc[split_id:, :-1].values, df.iloc[split_id:, -1].values

    y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
    batch_size = 512
    epochs = 8

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy']  # metrics=['categorical_accuracy']
    )

    history = model.fit(
        X_train[np.newaxis, ...],
        y_train[np.newaxis, ...],
        validation_split=0.1,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How many rows are in your data.csv?

Comment: Around 15K with 15 attributes. @IntuAi