# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_outputs' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am writing machine learning code using Keras to grade the severity of prostate cancer. After running it the following error appears:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-0e08590512ec> in <module>
      8     for file in column:
      9         data = generate_tiles(file)
---> 10         prediction = model.predict(data)
     11         max_score = prediction.max()
     12 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     86       raise ValueError('{} is not supported in multi-worker mode.'.format(
     87           method.__name__))
---> 88     return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     89 
     90   return tf_decorator.make_decorator(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1283             callbacks.on_predict_batch_end(step, {'outputs': batch_outputs})
   1284       callbacks.on_predict_end()
-> 1285     all_outputs = nest.map_structure_up_to(batch_outputs, concat, outputs)
   1286     return tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(all_outputs)
   1287 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_outputs' referenced before assignment
```

Does anyone know what batch outputs would be refering too? I don't have such a variable in my code.

Comment: I suspect that your `generate_tiles()` function returned an empty list or something similar, that caused some loop deep inside keras to execute zero times, and therefore never initialize some variable that gets used after the loop.

Comment: @user10055134 I am facing the same issue. any  workaround ?

Comment: @Gauranga it is as the previous comment said, my function returned an empty list. I think I just put in an if statement to check if it returned an empty list. That fixed it for my case since it wasn't as important, but if your case is more complex you might need to do something else

Answer (score 19):

This error is usually thrown when you pass an empty array to Keras. Check the array you are passing.

Comment: Why doesn't it just state you passed an empty array?

Comment: @Avedis Good Question :)

Comment: Aside from the incompleteness of the input variables, such as arrays inside the code, the issue is also as a result of inconsistencies between different versions of tensorflow and keras. I had the same issue. Instead of refactoring the way I was representing my arrays, I simply used a different version, where it was allowed to directly use the empty arrays. In my case I imported a different version of keras. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935988/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-batch-index-referenced-before-assignment

Answer (score 0):

I had to import the correct libraries (Tensorflow and not Keras directly):

#### instead of importing directly Keras:

```
from tensorflow.python import keras.models.Sequential
from tensorflow.python import keras.layers.Dense
```

#### importing of only tensorflow works:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
```

Apparently this is related to the different version issue of Keras. 2.2.4-tf 2.2.5 vs 1.14.0

P.s. Check your versions!!

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
print(keras.__version__)
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)
```